# PHP PDO Mysql Insert fails, throws no exception or error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

**Summary:**

I have a function that I'm using to set a key value pair in a MySQL database with PHP, it calls a utility function that does all of the inserting. I know this utility function works (use it with other functions) but for some reason, it is failing to insert the record.

The part that is confusing is that it does NOT throw a PDO Exception, I have the proper errmode set in the connection function so it is confusing me as to why I am getting no response.

Any idea how to resolve this or get it to provide an error?

**Function that takes an id and assigns a key/value to it in the database**

```
function setCredit($id){
//sets credit bool
//table to insert
$table='accountMeta';
//key
$key="isCredit";
//key value
$value="Y";
//array that is generated to insert 
$valueArray=array("id"=>$id,"key"=>$key,"value"=>$value,"date"=>mysqlTime(currentDate()));
if (isset($id)){
    //run the insert if $id exists
    $results=insert($valueArray,$table);
    echo $results;

} else {
    //fail if $id doesn't exist
    $results="ERROR: Invalid Inputs";

}
return $results;}
```

**Utility Function that does the inserting**

```
function insert($array,$table){
//$array should be formatted like "column"=>"data",... etc
$columns="";
$values="";
//generate the insert statement
foreach ($array as $id=>$val){
    $columns.=$id.",";
    $columnBind.=":".$id.",";

}

    //cut off some extra commas after our foreach
$columns=rtrim($columns,",");
$columnBind=rtrim($columnBind,",");
    //get dat connection
$DBH=dbConn();

    //prep the PDO


$sql=$DBH->prepare("Insert into $table($columns) VALUES($columnBind)");

//bind each value in the PDO
foreach ($array as $id=>$val){
    $sql->bindValue(":$id",$val);   

}

try{
    //give'r a go
    $sql->execute();
    return "SUCCESS";
} catch (PDOExecption $e){
    //and if she says no:
    return "ERROR: Failed to Insert";
    logMessage("select ".$e->getMessage());
   }
}
```

**Database Connection Function**

```
function dbConn(){
$dbName=confLine("databaseName");
$dbUser=confLine("databaseUser");
$dbPass=confLine("databasePass");
$dbAddress=confLine("databaseAddress");
try{
    $DBH=new PDO("mysql:host=$dbAddress;dbname=$dbName","$dbUser","$dbPass");
    $DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e){
    echo "Err connecting to DB";
    logMessage("dbConn ".$e->getMessage());
    exit;
}
  return $DBH;
}
```

Comment: You're very likely just not committing.   Please read http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php

Comment: Are you displaying errors? Your dev environment `php.ini` file should have `display_errors = On` and `error_reporting = E_ALL`

Comment: @BadZen That seems pretty unlikely considering OP isn't using transactions and hasn't (visibly) disabled auto-commit

Comment: Also, how far does your execution get? Do you get *"SUCCESS"* back from your `setCredit()` function? Maybe try stepping through with a debugger

Comment: Auto-commit can be disabled in lots of places (php.ini for one) and if his log file is not seeing an error and no runtime errors are generated otherwise there aren't many other possibilities.  This has definitely bitten me before.

Comment: @Phil, display_errors=on, error_reporting=E_ALL

Comment: @Phil, No response back what so ever. Added some echos and the function gets as far as the execute();

Comment: @BadZen I can't see any `php.ini` config values for auto-commit. Got a link?

Comment: @Phil, I forgot to restart apache after altering my php.ini. It is now throwing errors. I can see what I am doing wrong and can actually work on the issue now.

Comment: @JamesY I was about to say, you should at least have an *undefined variable* notice for `$columnBind`

Comment: Phil, put it up as an answer up so I can +1 you! :)

Comment: @JamesY telling somebody to display errors when developing isn't an answer, it's a debugging suggestion.

Comment: Technically debugging was what I was asking for. I'll answer my own question in detail on what caused the error and cite you. Thanks!

Comment: php.ini settings for driver autocommit are driver-specific.   However, reading the doc page I posted carefully it seems the semantics for PDO autocommit are better than they used to be (ie. well-defined and not dependent on underlying driver).

Answer (score 1):

**The Answer**

2 issues arose:

PHP.ini wasn't set up to provide the error verbosity required. Thanks to @Phil who suggested in the comments to set display_errors=on, error_reporting=E_ALL in the php.ini file.

After this, I was presented with this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or  access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key,value,date) VALUES('9','isCredit','Y','2014-09-21')' at line 1' in /var/www/html/finance/PHP/utils.inc:133 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/finance/PHP/utils.inc(133): PDOStatement->execute() #1 /var/www/html/finance/PHP/functions.inc(116): insert(Array, 'accountMeta') #2 /var/www/html/finance/PHP/setCredit.php(5): setCredit('9') #3 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/finance/PHP/utils.inc on line 133

After some very short looking into there error, I found out that I was using a reserved word in mysql. A completely obvious one, I was using 'key' as a column name. Once I changed the column name to something not reserved, the insert was successful.

Comment: Funny you should post that. When I saw the word `key`, I immediately thought "[reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)", but didn't say anything because and TBH, I couldn't exactly follow how your code worked. So that's what it was then. Glad you found it.